# Hermite polynomials in Kreyszig.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

For the sake of completeness, I reproduce the whole topic. I didn't understand why what I underlined in red is zero. Furthermore the explanation I underlined in yellow why is it true? I had thought of the Dominated Convergence Theorem, but how can I conclude that, in general, $v^{(n-m)}$ belongs to $L^1(-\infty,+\infty)$?
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Consider making the image smaller so the post is easier to read

Comment: Hint: $v^{(n-1)}$ is a derivative of $e^{-t^2}\,.$ When you multiply that with a polynomial of arbitrary degree you should be able to show that the product of those functions is zero at $\pm\infty\,.$ L'Hospital should work.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks! And as for the line in yellow can you suggest me something?

Comment: By fundamental theorem of calculus, $\int_{-a}^a v^{(n-m)}\,dt=v^{(n-m+1)}(a)-v^{(n-m+1)}(-a)\,.$ Now let $a$ tend to $\infty.$